# How to retreive ContactKey of the subscriber in the SMS message

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, mobileconnect, sms

I need to retrieve a value from a data extension (DE) into the SMS message. Specifically, the GlobalID value which is the same as the contact key. The contact key is existing in the system table - all contacts. I don’t want to use any personalization string such as %%contactid%%. I need the GlobalID/ContactKey value to be associated with a variable (for example @Global = ???DE field/System Field???)

- Name of the DE: MobileConnect_Test
- Fields in the DE:

  - GlobalID (Text)
  - Phone    (Phone)
  - Locale   (Locale)
  - Name     (Text)

I have used functions such as AttributeValue, lookup for the source DE, and I also tried retrieving the contact key, but nothing worked for me. When I test it out with the preview and test tool in an email, it works, but I need this to work for SMS as well. The amp script in the SMS message is below:

```
%%[

VAR
@link,
@UTM, 
@SubKey,
@link2

SET @link = URLEncode('https://www.google.com/')

SET @UTM = "?GlobalID="

SET @SubKey= AttributeValue("GlobalID") /* <--- variations of tis part are causing errors */

SET @link2 = Concat(@link, @UTM, @SubKey)

]%%


The result: %%=v(@link2)=%%
```

Comment: How are you sending the message? Send 2 DE? List send? JB?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the reason why it was not working is that I have not checked the box "concatenate message". Since the amp script part was divided into more than 2 SMS messages, it was causing errors.